# Pure CSS Collapse Accordion

Tags: html, css, accordion

I have a CSS collapse accordion with just pure CSS, it is working perfect.

I have just 1 issue:
right now if the user click in any label: Label One, Label Two, Label Three, he can't close it clicking in Label  again, each label can just close if the user clicks in the next one

I would like make it possible,

example: the user click in Label One to open, if him click again this label will close and the same will all for all labels.

js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/11wunqqz/4/

```css
/* Acordeon styles */

.tab {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  background: #16a085;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.blue label {
  background: #2980b9;
}

.tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #1abc9c;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .35s;
  -o-transition: max-height .35s;
  transition: max-height .35s;
}

.blue .tab-content {
  background: #3498db;
}

.tab-content p {
  margin: 1em;
}


/* :checked */

input:checked ~ .tab-content {
  max-height: 10em;
}


/* Icon */

label::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -o-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
  content: "+";
}

input[type=radio] + label::after {
  content: "\25BC";
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tab blue">
    <input id="tab-four" type="radio" name="tabs2">
    <label for="tab-four">Label One</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab blue">
    <input id="tab-five" type="radio" name="tabs2">
    <label for="tab-five">Label Two</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab blue">
    <input id="tab-six" type="radio" name="tabs2">
    <label for="tab-six">Label Three</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not directly possible using radio buttons - because clicking the label for an already checked button doesn’t un-check it again, _only_ choosing a different radio will do that. If you’re willing to further complicate this, then you could put a second label into each item, that targets an additional radio button (can be the same for all) - if that label is clicked, it will check that new additional radio button, meaning the one associated with the current item will become un-checked again. And you show/hide the _correct_ label based on the radio button state too.

Comment: Worth the hassle? Rather not, if you ask me - because this accordion has accessibility issues already, a keyboard user would expect that they tab to the controls and then use [enter] to activate an item, but because it’s labels that doesn’t work. Using standard JavaScript this would be easy with a _proper_ DOM structure for an accordion ...

Comment: jQuery is not that hard man

Answer (score 3):

It runs perfectly when u change type radio to type checkbox.
https://jsfiddle.net/4xvsn17y/

```css
/* Acordeon styles */

.tab {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  background: #16a085;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.blue label {
  background: #2980b9;
}

.tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #1abc9c;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .35s;
  -o-transition: max-height .35s;
  transition: max-height .35s;
}

.blue .tab-content {
  background: #3498db;
}

.tab-content p {
  margin: 1em;
}


/* :checked */

input:checked ~ .tab-content {
  max-height: 10em;
}


/* Icon */

label::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -o-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label::after {
  content: "+";
}

input[type=radio] + label::after {
  content: "\25BC";
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tab blue">
    <input id="tab-four" type="checkbox" name="tabs2">
    <label for="tab-four">Label One</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab blue">
    <input id="tab-five" type="checkbox" name="tabs2">
    <label for="tab-five">Label Two</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab blue">
    <input id="tab-six" type="checkbox" name="tabs2">
    <label for="tab-six">Label Three</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the radio type will cause the problem, because it has only 2 "data-way".

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Jquery this code may help you

this is html

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="group">
        <a href="#" class="title">title 1</a>
        <div class="content">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <a href="#" class="title">title 2</a>
        <div class="content">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <a href="#" class="title">title 3</a>
        <div class="content">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is css

```
.title{
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            background: #ccc;
            color: #fff;
            border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
        }
        .group .content{
            display: none;
            padding: 10px;
            background: #43ad43;
            color: #fff;
        }
        .open .title{
            background: green !important;
            border-bottom:none;
        }
        .open .content{
            display: block;
        }
```

and this is jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.title').on('click',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var parent=$(this).parent();


            if (parent.hasClass('open')) {
               parent.removeClass('open')
            }
            else{
                $(".group").removeClass("open");
                parent.addClass("open");
            }

        })
    });
```